# kubernetes: can't ping pods

Tags: kubernetes, ping, kubernetes-pod

I created a k8s cluster which network configuration to pod is `podSubnet: 172.168.0.0/12`

Then, I find that can't ping those pod's IP.
for example, the deployment of metrics

```
# on k8s-master01 node:
$ kubectl get po -n kube-system -o wide
metrics-server-545b8b99c6-r2ql5   1/1  Running 0 5d1h  172.171.14.193  k8s-node02     <none>           <none>

# ping 172.171.14.193 -c 2
PING 172.171.14.193 (172.171.14.193) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.171.14.193 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1016ms

# this is route table
# route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.180.104.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.180.104.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.161.125.0   10.180.104.110  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.162.195.0   10.180.104.109  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.169.92.64   10.180.104.108  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.169.244.192 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali06e1673851f
172.169.244.192 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
172.171.14.192  10.180.104.111  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
```

that shows metric pod host on `k8s-node02`. This is k8s-node02's route table

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table of k8s-master01
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.180.104.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.180.104.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.180.104.11   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.161.125.0   10.180.104.110  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.162.195.0   10.180.104.109  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.169.92.64   10.180.104.108  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.169.244.192 10.180.104.107  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
172.171.14.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
172.171.14.193  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali872eed170f4
172.171.14.194  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali7d7625dd37e
172.171.14.203  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 calid4e258f95f6
172.171.14.204  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali5cf96eb1028
```

in fact, all pods can't access. I created a service based on example deployment.

```
# kubectl describe svc my-service
Name:              my-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=demo-nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.100.75.139
IPs:               10.100.75.139
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.161.125.14:80,172.161.125.15:80,172.171.14.203:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

# ping 10.100.75.139 -c 1
PING 10.100.75.139 (10.100.75.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.100.75.139: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms

# nc -vz 10.100.75.139 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

I suppose that the root cause is route table but not sure. Would you please help to fix this issue??

please feel free to let me know if you need more information.

Thanks a lot in advance.

BR//

Comment: could you do a kubectl describe of the pod as well? is that ip the same?

Comment: yes. that's same
# kubectl describe po metrics-server-545b8b99c6-r2ql5 -n kube-system | grep IP
IP:                   172.171.14.193
IPs:
  IP:           172.171.14.193

Comment: is it possible that you shared that ? could you also do a kubectl logs of the pod. however, easiest way to confirm ping is to expose the pod and ping it through the service. there is some k8s networking involve here. try kubectl expose pod more at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose

Comment: I created a service upon the deployment, can ping service's IP but failed to test its port via nc.
```
# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
my-service   ClusterIP   10.100.75.139   <none>        80/TCP    3h28m

# ping 10.100.75.139 -c 1
PING 10.100.75.139 (10.100.75.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.100.75.139: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms

# nc -vz 10.100.75.139 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out
```

Comment: out of curiosity, do you mind sharing what is the image?

Comment: sure, 
the command: kubectl describe deploy/demo-nginx | grep Image
return: Image:      nginx

Comment: I tested this in my another k8s cluster at home which identical network configuration. No issue occurred, I think upstream network team of company  block something.

Comment: got it !! thats interesting, i would be interested to understand what that is if you ever find out ! maybe network team has blocked access to the node

Answer (score 0):

**In connect mode, Ncat initiates a connection (or sends UDP data) to a service that is listening somewhere**. For those familiar with socket programming, connect mode is like using the connect function. In listen mode, Ncat waits for an incoming connection (or data receipt), like using the bind and listen to functions.

A **connection timed out** response indicates that your connection is not working, which could mean your firewall is blocking the port. Test the connection status by adding a rule that accepts connections on the required port.

There might be issues with traffic rules, try adding outbound traffic rules in security groups if you face the error again. Even after adding the traffic rules, if you face the same error then there must be some restricting rules on the node which is blocking you from accessing the port.

Refer to [Testing Network services](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/testing-network-services-with-netcat/) for more information.